# gradle-4.8 build failed with an exception which could not get the internet resource

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, ubuntu-18.04

After I change my OS to Ubuntu-18.04 and upgrade grade to v4.8, I failed to build my android project.

As a comparison, I can build this project on Ubuntu-14.04 with gradle-v3.4.1.

There are some error messages.

Gradle build failed as following:

```
user@Ubuntu1804 ~/android/im/ocelot $ gradle build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'ocelot'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

This is the build.gradle:

```
user@Ubuntu1804 ~/android/im/ocelot $ cat build.gradle 
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is the gradle version:

```
user@Ubuntu1804 ~/android/im/ocelot $ gradle -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.8
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-06-04 10:39:58 UTC
Revision:     9e1261240e412cbf61a5e3a5ab734f232b2f887d

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_171 (Oracle Corporation 25.171-b11)
OS:           Linux 4.15.0-23-generic amd64
```

OpenJDK-1.8.0:

```
user@Ubuntu1804 ~/android/im/ocelot $ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

I already imported some cacerts and verified them as following:

```
user@Ubuntu1804 ~/android/im/ocelot $ keytool -list -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts | grep google
Enter keystore password:  changeit
google.com, Jun 21, 2018, trustedCertEntry, 
debian:googlecom.pem, Jun 21, 2018, trustedCertEntry, 
dl.google.com, Jun 21, 2018, trustedCertEntry, 
maven.google.com, Jun 21, 2018, trustedCertEntry, 

user@Ubuntu1804 ~/android/im/ocelot $ keytool -list -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts | grep bintray
Enter keystore password:  changeit
jcenter.bintray.com, Jun 21, 2018, trustedCertEntry,
```

I did some tests to verify the internet connection because there is one HTTPS_PROXY:

```
user@Ubuntu1804 ~/android/im/ocelot $ wget https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom
--2018-06-21 22:21:27--  https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom
Resolving proxy.COMPANY.net (proxy.COMPANY.net)... 10.x.x.x
Connecting to proxy.COMPANY.net (proxy.COMPANY.net)|10.x.x.x|:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom [following]
--2018-06-21 22:21:28--  https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom
Connecting to proxy.COMPANY.net (proxy.COMPANY.net)|10.x.x.x|:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2391 (2.3K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘gradle-3.1.2.pom.1’

gradle-3.1.2.pom.1             100%[====================================================>]   2.33K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2018-06-21 22:21:29 (17.1 MB/s) - ‘gradle-3.1.2.pom.1’ saved [2391/2391]

user@Ubuntu1804 ~/android/im/ocelot $ curl https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

Comment: can you update your question with project level `build.gradle`?

Comment: Updated. and Thanks for your comment.

Comment: can you try to use `maven {
     url 'https://maven.google.com'
}` instead of `google()` ?

Comment: Still got the same exception result.

Comment: Since it was trying to check `'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2` I thought changing the URL would help. Can you check if your internet is stable?

Comment: There is one HTTPS_PROXY, however I think it is stable. Because I can download the https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom using wget manually, however I cannot download it with curl.

$ curl https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Comment: may be you can try `3.1.3` version

Comment: with 3.1.3 still got failed.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a `truststore` issue.

Try running your build with: `./gradlew --no-daemon -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose build`

And check which `truststore` gets loaded and which certificates it contains, by looking for lines `adding as trusted cert:`.